# how to implement this scenario car class have 3 methods(m1,m2,m3) and engineer can access m1 and m2, and driver can access m1 and m3 mthod

Tags: java

I have car class and three methods m1(),m2(),m3(). engineer can access m1() and m2()method ,driver can m1() and m3(),but for engineer restrict m3()(should not provide for accessing this method) and for driver restrict m2()(should not provide for accessing this method)method how to implement this scenario in JAVA
class car{

}

Answer (score 0):

Declare the car as interface with m3() method and then create engineer interface with which extends car interface and has m2() method and similarly a driver interface with m3() method and which extends car interface.Now write a ConcreteEngineer class which implements engineer interface and a ConcreteDriver class to implement driver interface.